# Relative Layout containing FrameLayout and few other components

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

firstly excuse me for terrible naming with the subject.

I have the following layout setup:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PersonDetails" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bannerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/coverImage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/default_cover">
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left|bottom"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/fingerprint_ic" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textColor="#55FF55"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What i am trying to achieve is to have a banner (much like facebook cover that spans across the top of the screen). And have a thumbnail photo at the corner left of the banner.

The height of the banner should only takes up about 1/4 of the height of the screen. Since i would need the rest of the space for other components.

Immediately below the banner i would like to have a TextView (on the leftside) and a button on the rightside.

So far i can only able to put the thumbnail on top of the banner, but i don't know how to place it on the lower left (i could set it using marginTop but, i believe this is not the correct way of doing it).

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks.

EDIT #1:

Here is the UI

[image: Custom Layout]

Comment: provide some ui diagrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description i think you want to make something like this:

I used a linearlayout with 2 layouts as content. Using the android:layout_weight attribute we can make the top layout take up 1/4th of the space, while the bottom layout has the rest to use.

Then to position the icon in the top layout we use alignParentBottom to make it stick to the bottom.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".PersonDetails"
android:orientation="vertical">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bannerLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/coverImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/default_cover"></ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/fingerprint_ic" />
</RelativeLayout>



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textColor="#55FF55"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i am trying to achieve. I thought i could use FrameLayout for this. Thanks for the help.